# lock a part of value in input tag

Tags: html

suppose my input include two part, country and name.The part of name could change the value arbitrarily and the part of country's value is decided by an select only. How can I lock the value of country part ? perhaps separate a input into two is a better idea?

Comment: Definitly use seperate controls. An `<input>` and a `<select>`. From a cohesion stand point those values are also not forming a meaningful whole. Well, they could be part of a bigger concept such as ContactInformation, but they aren't cohesive at a more fine grained level like firstName and lastName would be to form a FullName concept. Why did you though about aggregate both values in the same field?

Comment: Yes,  use two fields.

Comment: I suppose that you don't need an input for 'country', just a `span` or just the selector.

Comment: you may put your code here.

Comment: thank you for answer. i think i have a idea .

Comment: what do you mean 'lock the value'. Do you want to lock country till the user fill the name?